# Tough jQuery template question

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

Let's say I have a template like this

```
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <a href="${ $.tmpl(viewModel.EditUrl, $data).text() }">Edit </a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="${ $.tmpl(viewModel.DetailsUrl, $data).text() }">Details</a></td>
        <td>${Id}</td>
        <td>${Number}</td>
        <td>${Description}</td>
        <td>${Total}</td>
        <td><input type='image' src="/images/delete.gif" alt="delete" data-bind="click: function() { processCommand({name:'Delete', Data: this, IsAjax:false}) }"></a></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Obviously we are binding a collection and for each entry, a row is created. Now what I cannot get is to refer to the instance of the "data" being bound but have to reach into global "viewModel" variable. I would like to get the instance of the data being bound, and get the property "EditUrl" (which itself has a template text). So how do I do that?

Full example ( I use also knockout.js but the question is not about it)
Problem is that I bind a list of "Dtos" to a rows. But EditUrl and CreateUrl are not on the Dtos, but on the object that contains Dtos ( a parent).

```
   var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS({"Dtos":[{"Id":0,
"Description":"some description",
"Number":0,"Total":0.0,
"Date":"\/Date(1303495442114-0500)\/"},
{"Id":1,"Description":"some description","Number":100,"Total":200.0,
"Date":"\/Date(1271959442114-0500)\/"},
{"Id":2,"Description":"some description","Number":200,"Total":400.0,
"Date":"\/Date(1240423442114-0500)\/"},"CreateUrl":"http://localhost:16555/TestOrderProcessingPage/tabid/63/ctl/OrderEdit/orderId/-1/Default.aspx",
"EditUrl":"http://localhost:16555/TestOrderProcessingPage/tabid/63/ctl/OrderEdit/mid/387/Default.aspx?orderId=${Id}",
"DetailsUrl":"http://localhost:16555/TestOrderProcessingPage/tabid/63/ctl/OrderDetails/mid/387/Default.aspx?orderId=${Id}"});

<div data-bind='template: {name: "contentTemplate"}' />

<script id="contentTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{tmpl contentHeaderTemplate}}
    <div data-bind='template: {name: "tableTemplate"}'></div>
    <br />
</script>

<script id="contentHeaderTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<h2>
    Orders</h2>
<a href="${CreateUrl}">
    Create New Order</a>
<br />
<br />
</script>

<script id="tableTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <table class="gridview" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1">

        <tbody data-bind='template: {name:"rowTemplate", foreach:Dtos}'></tbody>

    </table>
</script>

<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr>
    //this is problem "viewModel", there is not global viewModel variable any more, so the question is how to refer to data being bound to the row.
        <td><a href="${ $.tmpl(viewModel.EditUrl, $data).text() }">Edit </a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="${ $.tmpl(viewModel.DetailsUrl, $data).text() }">Details</a></td>
        <td>${Id}</td>
        <td>${Number}</td>
        <td>${Description}</td>
        <td>${Total}</td>
        <td><input type='image' src="/images/delete.gif" alt="delete" data-bind="click: function() { processCommand({name:'Delete', Data: this, IsAjax:false}) }"></a></td>
    </tr>
</script>

<script id="headerTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</script>
```

Comment: Could you post up an example of the JSON you're using?  Also this article might help - http://encosia.com/2010/11/10/composition-with-jquery-templates-why-and-how/

Comment: It would help a little more to give more details about the template `viewModel` and also the a sample from the json object in play here

Comment: @Floyd Pink: full example added.

Comment: You seem to be missing a ] in your JSON there.  /"}],"CreateUrl"

Comment: @Nicky Waites: Probably when I was cleaning the extra data. It really is not missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is pass in the the viewModel or the variables that you need in through the "options" parameter to jQuery templates.

I am thinking that you are using Knockout here, so what you can do is something like:

```
<table data-bind="template: { name: 'rowTemplate', foreach: myRows, templateOptions: { edit: EditUrl, details: DetailsUrl } }"></table>
```

Then, in your template you can access these properties in the row template like:

`$item.edit` and `$item.details` (or whatever you want to call your properties).

If you are not using Knockout, then you can pass options into `$.tmpl` like:

```
$( "#myTemplate" ).tmpl(yourData, { option1: value1, option2: value2 }).appendTo( "#target") );
```

Comment: @RP Niemeyer: when I add that part for template options it breaks and does not render at all. I am using 1.1.2 knockout.js

Comment: I see that you updated your question.  Only change to my answer is that EditUrl and DetailsUrl are observables, so you will need to do `templateOptions: { edit: EditUrl(), details: DetailsUrl() }`.  Also, make sure that you are using Knockout 1.2 (not 1.12)

Comment: @ RP Niemeyer: Is there a new version for knockout.mapping.js plugin?

Comment: There are some fixes in the current mapping plugin code, but no new official release of it.

Comment: One other tip: if you specify templateOptions make sure that there is a space between the closing brace for it and the closing brace for the template binding.  If you do }}, then jQuery templates gets confused.

Comment: @RP Niemeyer: Sorry but this just does not work. I create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/epitka/BwZAz/7/ if you want to take a look please.

Comment: It looks like your only issue is here: 
`<tbody data-bind='template: {name:"rowTemplate", foreach:Dtos, templateOptions:{ editUrl: EditUrl(), detailsUrl:DetailsUrl()} }'></tbody>`

EditUrl and DetailsUrl are not observables in your model, so it should just look like:

`<tbody data-bind='template: {name:"rowTemplate", foreach:Dtos, templateOptions:{ editUrl: EditUrl, detailsUrl:DetailsUrl} }'></tbody>`

Comment: @RP Niemeyer: Aha, that is beacause in this examle I did not use mapping plugin, I suppose?. Thank RP very much.